# NodeJS module get compiled

Tags: node.js, time

I have create a simple nodejs module that return current time

it works only first time, after first call it will be cached and will return first call value

**This is my module:**

```
module.exports.Time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define it as a function that returns the time

```
module.exports.Time = function(){ return Math.floor(Date.now()/1000};

//Other file
var anything = require("path/file.js");
anything.Time();
```